# Binary Classification using Machine Learning Models for longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, random-forest, boosting, elastic-net

So I have longitudinal data with a binary target variable, and I'd like to perform binary classification using a random forest, xgboost, and glmnet (ridge/lasso/elastic net) model. Is this possible to do in r? I've skimmed a few articles where some algorithms are being developed but I've yet to see them fully published or available in r.

Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Instead of looking for “binary classification” look for “binary regression” or “logistic regression.” Include time as a predictor variable, flexibly modeled e.g. with a regression spline. Correct for correlations with a robust cluster variance, or use a mixed model with random effects for individuals.